# Преобразовать пары родитель-наследник в маршрут

Tags: c++, алгоритм, qt, графы, qt4

Понадобилось мне найти на неориентированном невзвешенном графе кратчайшие пути от всех ко всем. Немного погуглив наткнулся на алгоритм Дейкстры. На выходе этого алгоритма я получаю что-то вроде `QMap<int, int>`. Первый `int` это родитель, второй - наследник в кратчайшем пути.

Например, если искать пути к вершинам начиная с нуля в таком графе:

[image: Граф]

Я получу такой набор:
0 - 0
1 - 0
2 - 3
3 - 1
4 - 1

Теперь вопрос, как это эффективно преобразовать в пути?

Сейчас делаю это так:

```
//Поиск родителя
QMap<int, int>::ConstIterator findParent(const QMap<int, int> &map,
                                         int child){
    QMap<int, int>::ConstIterator parent = map.find(child);

    if(child == *parent){
        return map.end();
    }

    return parent;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Построение маршрута
QVector<int> route(const QMap<int, int> &map,
                   int start){
    QVector<int> route;
    route.append(start);

    forever{
        QMap<int, int>::ConstIterator parent = findParent(map, route.last());

        if(parent == map.end()){
            break;
        }

        route.append(*parent);
    };

    return route;
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------
//Построение маршрутов
QVector<QVector<int> > routes(const QMap<int, int> &map){
    QVector<QVector<int> > routes;
    QMap<int, int>::ConstIterator begin = map.begin();
    QMap<int, int>::ConstIterator end = map.end();

    for(; begin != end; ++begin){
        routes.append(route(map, begin.key()));
    }

    return routes;
}
```

Оно работает и даже правильно. Но меня терзают сомнения это это самый эффективный способ. Я по многу раз ищу в карте один и те же значения. Возможно можно как-то построить маршруты за один проход по `QMap<int, int>`, или строить маршруты сразу, когда выполняется алгоритм?

[Минимальный пример](http://pastebin.com/t5bu7uS6) если вдруг кому-то понадобится

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Самый эффективный способ здесь - это проход по дереву от листа к корню. Для этого нужно сначала преобразовать ваш хэш в массив. То есть будет массив `p` с такими значениями `p[] = {0, 0, 3, 1, 1}`. Очень удобно, так как множественный проход по массиву очень быстрый и условие `i==p[i]` означает, что дошли до исходной точки.

Далее, чтобы построить путь, скажем, до вершины `x`, нужно просто идти по дереву до тех пор, пока не найдём корень. Примерный псевдокод:

```
x = желаемая_вершина;
do {
  way[k++] = x;
  x = p[x];
} while (x!=p[x]);
```

В массиве `way` будет искомый путь **задом наперёд**. Нужно выполнить этот цикл для всех `x`, для которых нужно найти путь. Тормоза у вас в реализации будут в первую очередь из-за неэффективного хранения дерева, а не из-за того, что какие-то участки проходите несколько раз. При указанном же подходе тормоза маловероятны. Ну если только у вас не десятки тысяч вершин.

Ещё замечание. Алгоритм Дейкстры здесь **неэффективен**, он ищет путь во взвешенном графе, более быстрый способ искать кратчайший путь в не взвешенном графе - это [поиск в ширину](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/bfs). Ежели вы всё-таки хотите именно Дейкстру, то нет смысла оптимизировать восстановление путей, потому что тормоза будут именно в Дейкстре.